# Make input-group same height as col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with two rows (`col-md-6`). On the left side there are some fields, on the right side, there's only one textarea.

Now what I wanted to do is make the textarea the same height as all the other fields together. 
I thought this would be easily possible when setting a `display: flex;` to the row, so that the tow `col-md-6`'s are the same height and then add `height: 100%` to the `input-group`, but unfortunately I was wrong. The input will not expand to the full height.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="row" style="display: flex;">

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Input 1:</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Input 2:</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Input 3:</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group" style="height: 100%;">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Textarea:</div>
      <textarea class="form-control" style="height: 100%"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I added the styles inline to reduce the code here on stackoverflow.

So again, I could get the two columns to the same height, but I'm unable to set the height of the textarea to 100%.

Can anyone tell how this could work? If possible without JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

```css
textarea {
  height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row" style="display: flex;">

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Input 1:</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Input 2:</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Input 3:</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group" style="height: 100%;">
      <div class="input-group-addon">Textarea:</div>
      <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What are you looking for then? This example has the textarea height set to 100%

Comment: Your code snippet does not work for me. It returns a "Script error" error message. But I've already made exactly what you did, and the textarea did not expand.

Comment: Could you update your original question with the current code you have?